# Возможно ли получить 3D модель человека из Kinect или аналогичной 3D-камеры?

Tags: 3d

Нужно получить 3D-модель в отдельном формате. Kinect вроде не отдает наружу свои модели, может кто знает способ как получить?

Comment: Отдает.Eще с SDK1